# Manage text overflow with a span inside a div inside a table cell

Tags: html, css, text, overflow

I've a long text inside a span element and I want to truncate it using ellipsis.
The span element is inside a div element which is inside a table cell.

How can I truncate the long text at the size of the cell.

Here the HTML code snippet:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <div> 
       <span>
         this is a long sentence to test the text overflow
       </span>
     </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

And the CSS code:

```
table {
 width: 50px;
 table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
 border: 1px solid red;
}

span {
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here my case in JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fedy2/wG3CF/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test this example my friends!

```
 span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Here the updated JSFiddle snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fedy2/wG3CF/3/

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use `<span>`?

Its working in `<p>` tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/wG3CF/2/